# $(document).ready equivalant in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to find equivalent code for jQuery $(document).ready, and find there are some different versions:

Version 1:

```
function ready(fn) {
  if (document.readyState != 'loading'){
    fn();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  }
}
```

Version 2:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
```

What is the difference? Why version 1 will check document.readyState? Also version 1 is a function, while version 2 is an executed statement. So should there be one statement for version 1:

```
ready(fn);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of jQuery has the answer to your question.

[jQuery.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> Most browsers provide similar functionality in the form of a `DOMContentLoaded` event. However, jQuery's `.ready()` method differs in an important and useful way: If the DOM becomes ready and the browser fires `DOMContentLoaded` before the code calls `.ready( handler )`, the function handler will still be executed. In contrast, a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener added after the event fires is never executed.…

So your **Version 2** has the described problem. While **Version 1** calls the passed function even after the document is already ready.

Comment: Oh that's funny. And of course. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that the first one will work even if the script is executed after `DOMContentLoaded` has fired (see [`document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) for more), provided you add the call to `ready` you asked about. The second won't, because the event is only fired once, so if the script is executed after that, `fn` will never get called.

So how could the script be executed after the event has already fired? Basically, if it's added dynamically, not as part of the document's initial HTML. Here are a couple of examples of how that could be:

- A `script` element added after the document has loaded.
- A module loaded via dynamic `import()` rather than static `import`.

There are probably others.

> Also version 1 is a function, while version 2 is an executed statement. So should there be one statement for version 1:
>
> ```
> ready(fn);
> ```

Yes, absolutely right.

---

I should note that you don't need *either* of those **if** you control how the script is included in the page. (So, you do need it in libraries, but rarely in apps/pages.) If you control how the script is included in the page, and want your code to run after the DOM has been built, here are several ways you can do that (IMHO, in order of best practice):

- Use `type="module"` on the script to make it a module. Modules aren't executed until the DOM has been built (they're auto-deferred, even inline modules; see the next bullet point).
- Use [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) on your `script` tag (only works for `src` script tags referring to files, not inline scripts). Deferred scripts aren't executed until the DOM has been built.
- Put the `script` tag at the end of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

If you do any of those things, there's no need to use `ready` (jQuery's or the ones in your question).